# regarding pseudo-prime numbers.

Tags: number-theory, pseudoprimes

If $W$ is an odd composite number and $-1+2^{W-1}$ is divisible by $W$ yet not by $W^2$, then $W^2$ does not divide $-1+ 2^{W(W-1)}$. Is this true? (forgive my use of symbols,I have no good math editing program that's easy to use.)

Comment: Can you share your thoughts so far?

Comment: W is a 2-pseudo-prime. If -1+2^(w-1) is not divisible by W^2 then -1+2^(W(W-1)) is not divisible by W^2 , if this is correct.   If V divides -1+2^(v-1) then V is a prime or a 2-pseudo-prime. If V is prime -1+2^(V(V-1))  is divisible by V^2. So to test for primes see if -1+2^(V(V-1)) is divisible by V^2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the converse is true:
If $p^k$ is a prime power dividing $W$, then $2^{W-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^k}$ implies $2^{p^k(W-1)}\equiv1\pmod{p^{2k}}$ (you can verify this with binomial expansion, but it's a well known result), hence $W^2\mid2^{W(W-1)}-1$.

Analoguous results hold for higher exponents: $W\mid2^{W-1}-1\implies W^n\mid2^{W^{n-1}(W-1)}-1$, i.e., $W$ 'behaves' as a prime, as if $\varphi(W^n)=W^{n-1}(W-1)$.

Comment: If W^2 does not divide -1+(2^(w-1)) does this imply W^2 does not divide -1+2^(W(W-1))??

Comment: No, the statement is even wrong, as I said in my answer: _"The converse is true."_ Is there still something unclear to you?

Comment: If 2^n(n-1) is congruent to T mod n^2 ,T is not congruent to 1 mod n^2 , T=Rn+U (0<U<n). Therefore (2^n(n-1))-1 is congruent to (T-1) mod n^2. Therefore n divides T-1. So n divides U-1 , thus U=1. So if n^2 does not divide 2^n(n-1) ; 2^n(n-1) = (Rn+1) mod n^2 , (0<=R<n)

Comment: If $2^{n(n-1)}\ equiv( T )\pmod{n^2}}$ , T is not congruent to 1 mod(n^2) and T = R n + U (0 < U < n). Therefore n | (T-1) so N | (U - 1) ,thus U = 1. So if $n^2$ does not divide  $2^{n(n - 1)}$ ; $2^{n(n-1)}\equiv(R n + 1)\pmod{n^2}$, ( 0 <= R < n)

Comment: If  2^(w(w-1)) is not congruent to 1 mod w^2 ( w being an odd composite) and 2^(w-1) = 1 mod w,   yet 2^( w-1) is not congruent to 1 mod w^2 is this a contradiction?